# Symfony Doctrine Group By

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2, symfony3

Мне нужно получить записи из базы данных в виде ассоциативного массива. У меня есть теплицы, растения и семьи которые связаны с связями (Один ко многим). В теплицах растут растения, у растений есть семьи, для теплицы нужно получить семьи. Поэтому теплица должна быть ключом - семьи значением. Моя попытка:

```
public function getFamiliesInGardens($client)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('g');

    $qb
        ->select(['g.name as garden', 'family.name', 'family.id'])
        ->join('g.growing', 'growing')
        ->join('growing.plant', 'plant')
        ->join('plant.family', 'family')
        ->where('g.client = :client')
        ->orderBy('g.name')
        ->addOrderBy('growing.endDate', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('client', $client);

    $grow = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    return $grow;
}
```

Я получаю:

```
[0] => array(3) {
    ["garden"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>string(9) "Brassicas"
    ["id"]=> int(13)
}
[1] =>
    array(3) {
    ["garden"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=> string(13) "Miscellaneous"
    ["id"]=> int(18)
    }
```

Но я ожидаю:

```
[0] => array(1) {
    ["1"] => array(2) {
        [0] => array(2) {
            ["name"] =>string(9) "Brassicas"
            ["id"] => int(13)
        },
        [1] => array(2) {
            ["name"]=>string(9) "Miscellaneous"
            ["id"]=> int(18)
        },
    }
}
```

Если добавить группировку по теплицам, результат будет тот же, но теплица будет повторятся один раз с одной семьей. Что нужно изменить, чтобы получить массив: garden => families?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так. `$grow = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`
К сожалению проверить сейчас не могу .

Comment: Тот же результат. Пока сделал это простым перебором массива.